# javascript remove string before a specific character

Tags: javascript, string

I've been looking and looking but can only find variations of the question I have...

I'm needing to remove a string before a character (including the character, and the spaces before and after the character). The string will be different each time and unpredictable, so no matter what it is it needs to be removed from the DOM. So, if this is the output:

```
<h2>Birds - Norwegian Yellow Finch</h2>
<h2>Cats - Domestic Shorthaired Tabby</h2>
<h2>Dogs - Alaskan Husky Cross</h2>
```

How do I remove "Birds - , Cats - , Dogs - "? And without being specific about those words (Birds, Cats, Dogs) because those will change. The dash (-) can be a different character, if needed (ie: *).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following loops through all h2 elements and removes the beginning via a regex replace:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var h2s = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"),
        i;

    for (i=0; i < h2s.length; i++)
        h2s[i].innerHTML = h2s[i].innerHTML.replace(/^[^-]+ - /,"");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nGfYd/5/

The `onload` handler ensures that the code runs after the page has finished loading, because JavaScript is executed as it is encountered while the page is being parsed, but it can only manipulate elements that have been already been parsed. You don't need the `onload` handler if you include the code in a script block after the elements in question, in fact my preference is to put the `<script>` block at the end of the body just before the closing `</body>` tag and not use an `onload` handler.

EDIT: From comments under other answers it seems you are happy to use jQuery, in which case you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h2").text(function(i, oldVal) {
        return oldVal.replace(/^[^-]+ - /,"");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nGfYd/7/

If you pass a function to `.text()` jQuery will call that function for each element, passing it the old (current) value of the element, so you don't need an `.each()` loop too.

(Again the document ready handler is not needed if you put the code in a script block at the end of the body.)

Comment: thank you. I should have mentioned that the string may sometimes be more than one word. Is that an easy adjustment? And what would it look like in a "onload handler"? (javascript beginner here)

Comment: I've updated my answer to show one way to code an `onload` handler, and explained a little more why you'd need one. Also, I tweaked the regex slightly to work for more than one word before the hyphen (note that some of the other answers would've already handled this possibility). Demo updated too.

Comment: Thanks again. I've wrapped your code in <script></script> and nothing happens. Feeling like a super noob right now :( What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know what you're missing. I thought maybe I had a typo or something, but a copy-paste from my answer into a jsfiddle worked with `<script>` tags here: http://jsfiddle.net/nGfYd/6/ If you put something simple like `<script>alert("Test");</script>` does it work?

Comment: Well, how strange. This works (copied from your newest demo):

`<script>
    var h2s = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"),
        i;

    for (i=0; i < h2s.length; i++)
        h2s[i].innerHTML = h2s[i].innerHTML.replace(/^[^-]+ - /,"");
</script>`

but not this (from the earlier demo):

`<script>
 var h2s = document.getElementsByTagName("h2"),
     i;

 for (i=0; i < h2s.length; i++)
     h2s[i].innerHTML = h2s[i].innerHTML.replace(/^[^-]+ - /,"");​
</script>`

And I can't see a difference.

Comment: I can't explain it. Except that the demo in my comment explicitly coded the `onload` function. The original demo in my question didn't explictly code it, but by default jsfiddle runs code in the JavaScript window `onload` unless you change that option from the drop-down on the left. Also, I added a jQuery solution to my answer.

Comment: Well, nonetheless, working now...thanks again for your answer(s) and quick reply(s).

Comment: Thanks again @nnnnnn...+1...the jquery example works as well as your pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using a regular expression http://jsfiddle.net/46G5c/:

```
$('h2').each(function() {
    var h2 = $(this);
    var text = h2.text();
    var replacement = text.substr(text.indexOf('- ') + 2);
    h2.text(replacement);
});​
```

And here is one that uses a regular expression which may or may not be more useful depending on your data http://jsfiddle.net/X3FTV/1/:

```
var regex = /^[^-]* - /;
$('h2').each(function() {
    var h2 = $(this);
    var text = h2.text();
    h2.text(text.replace(regex, ''));
});​
```

Both use jQuery but should be straight forward to change to plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. I like the option of Jquery because I've used quite a few plugins over the years so the syntax is a little more familiar. And the pages I need to use this on will actually already have the jquery library loaded. And your example is perfect because there will actually be more than one word sometimes as well as the possibility of a second dash. But I've wrapped your code in <script></script> and nothing happens. Feeling like a super noob right now :( What am I missing? (I have the jquery library loaded too)

Comment: You likely need to make sure it runs when the page has finished loading. So you would do `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`

Comment: Still not working for this beginner. Here's what I have, any advice: http://jsfiddle.net/8NcjJ/

Comment: You were missing the closing `});` on the function. It really helps to use correct indenting to catch these things and to look at the JavaScript console in Chrome/Firefox to figure out what is going wrong. Here is a fixed solution (also needed to set it to use jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/8NcjJ/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `RegExp` to solve this.

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Birds - Norwegian Yellow Finch</h2>
<h2>Cats - Domestic Shorthaired Tabby</h2>
<h2>Dogs - Alaskan Husky Cross</h2>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var re = /^[^-]+-\s*/;

function processText(el) {
    el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(re, '');
}

var elements = ​document.getElementsByTagName('h2')​​​​;

for(var i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {
    processText(elements[i]);
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/DrLD7/)

Comment: Thank you. Is it an easy adjustment to make this happen right away on page load? Your demo shows "run it" which is great...but I'm a javascript beginner and just don't know how to make this run on it's own.

Comment: Just execute the body of `onclick` handler directly.

Comment: I also see now that your code allows for the easy change of what element to apply the function to (one place to change "h2").